# wifi Manager wifiManager.addNetwork Stops my UI

Tags: android, wifi

i'm connecting to a wifi network in my app
and while i do that i show a user a costume dialog that has animation in it.

problem is that while i do this line >

```
wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
```

my animation in the dialog get's stuck and sometimes my app goes to not responding.

any idea on how to fix that ?

and if i can't show a dialog while connecting to a network, what do you suggest showing a user ?

this is my Connect to network function in my Wifi Wrapper class :

```
public void connectToNetwork(String ssidName, String netPassword, final Context applicationContext, final wifiConnectionEsteblishedInterface callback) { // in order to call callback from another thread it needs to be final

        final String networkSSID = ssidName;
        String networkPass = netPassword;

        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   // Please note the quotes. String should contain
        conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {

            if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {

                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();
                break;
            }
        }

        Log.d("myLogs", "log-0");

        callback.callbackFromWifi(); // calls the cllback


    }
```

and this is my dialog listener

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { //on button clicked

                        mainDialog.show(); //show main dialog back again

                        loaderScreenMainText.setText("Connecting to RADWIN WiFi"); // shows on screen message

                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
                                wifiWrapper WifiWrapper = new wifiWrapper();

                                WifiWrapper.toggleWiFi(Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this, true); // turns wifi ON

                                aligmentManager aligmentManager = new aligmentManager(); // tells the manager that we started looking for a wifi
                                aligmentManager.initlizedConnectingToWifi();


                                if (scanResults != null) { //in future use we will use scanResults veriable which is already initlized by now;

                                    WifiWrapper.connectToNetwork("nmsRoom", "12345678", getApplication(), callbackFunctionForisWifiConnection); //in the future we will pass the scan results to the network

                                    //

                                } else {
                                    //do something in case scan result fails

                                }


                            }
                        }, 500); //deley in order to start the animation before hand (otherwise the dialog shows after, 2, 3 seconds


                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting to the WiFi on the UI thread, which stops it until the code finishes. If you want the animation to run, you should put the connection code into an `AsyncTask`, or some other way to move it off the UI thread.

Comment: Thnx Allot, @Panel do you know a simpler way then opening an AsyncTask to do the Wifi Operation at ?

Comment: You can start a new Thread, override run() and copy your code there. Don't forget to call start() on it.

Comment: THNX it helped allot